# Used CPU and %idle CPU - whats the difference

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

Does the term "used" mean **`utilized`** and "Idle" Mean **`not utilized`**? I would like to understand below two scenarios.

**1. Find "used" CPU Using free Command** >  I get 96% used

```
[splunkuser@server: ~] # free | grep Mem | awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}'
96.3656

[splunkuser@server: ~] # free | awk '/Mem/{printf("used: %.2f%"), $3/$2*100} /buffers\/cache/{printf(", buffers: %.2f%"), $4/($3+$4)*100} /Swap/{printf(", swap: %.2f%\n"), $3/$2*100}'
used: 96.07%, buffers: 91.70%, swap: 5.60%
```

**2. Find "Idle" CPU using mpstat Command** > I get 93%

```
[splunkuser@server: ~] # mpstat
Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 (SERVER )         06/26/2019      _x86_64_        (56 CPU)

08:16:47 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
08:16:47 PM  all    3.56    0.00    0.95    1.65    0.00    0.09    0.00    0.00    0.00   93.74
```

Why do i get nearly the same result for **`used`** and for **`idle`**?

Comment: Who told you that the `free` command checked CPU utilization? `free` checks the system memory (RAM and swap) utilization. That is probably what is causing your confusion here.

Comment: I am sorry about my English, That is how i understand using basic english. Whats the difference between utilization and RAM, if i have understood you?

Comment: No worries! RAM is the system's memory, where it stores code and data. The CPU runs the code in order for the computer to work. RAM utilization and CPU utilization are two different things, which is why the numbers from your commands didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I think this confusion is everywhere since many question here at  stackexchange and stackoverflow confuse CPU and RAM. since i get some same answers when i search CPU utilization and RAM usage. i will have to research more and keenly having that in mind for better understanding